# Concurrent access of Network Stream on the same Machine

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6843064/c-sharp-networkstream-write-and-read) and the [Docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream(v=vs.110).aspx), it says that for concurrent stream access, read and write can be performed without a problem if there is ONE unique thread for read and ONE unique thread for write.

I'm having the following setup, also shown in picture below:

I have 2 separate services `Tester Service` and `My Service`. Each of them has a `Server` and a `Client`. Each of the Servers and Clients have 2 tasks `WriterTask` and `ReaderTask`.

The problem I am facing is that after certain time, the client gives an [IOException 10060](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7834780/c-sharp-tcp-socket-error-10060). When in fact, the server on the other side is running well.

Now, the documentation says one unique thread for read/write operation, is there a problem if it's on the same machine?

Anybody else faced a similar situation before?

[image]

Server Reader:

```
    private void ReaderTask(NetworkStream stream)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            // Some code
            try
            {
                if (stream.CanRead)
                {
                    var readTask = Task.Run(() =>
                    {
                        MyObj message = null;
                        try
                        {
                            message = Deserialize<MyObj>(stream);
                            Console.WriteLine("ReaderTask: Read");
                            // Some code
                        }
                        catch (IOException e)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("ReaderTask: " + e.Message);
                        }
                        return message;
                    });
                    while(!readTask.Wait(1000))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("ReaderTask: Wait 1000");
                    }
                    if (readTask.Result != null)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("ReaderTask: Message received" + readTask.Result.toString());
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ReaderTask: " + e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

Client Writer:

```
    private void WriterTask(NetworkStream stream)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            // Some code
            try
            {
                if (stream.CanWrite)
                {
                    // message = getMessage();
                    Serialize(stream, message);
                    Console.WriteLine("WriterTask: Write");
                    // Some code
                }
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("WriterTask: " + e.Message);
            }
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes, I faced a similar situation and the problem was in my code, not related to the separation between read and write threads. How do you know that "the server is running well"? Is there a thread currently blocking on the `NetworkStream.Read()` operation of the client that is crashing?

Comment: @C.Evenhuis "the server is running well" - the server's reader and writer tasks were generating logs. And so I knew they were fine. But the server's reader task was reading the stream in an async task which was blocking indefinitely. I've put detailed information in my answer below. If you have more information, it'd be nice if you post an answer and fill in more details.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out what the problem was.

I wasn't receiving any data from my server because, I didn't set a receive timeout on the client like this `client.ReceiveTimeout = 2000`. Because of this, the server would have it's `ReaderTask` blocked on the read call.

I'm not 100% sure as to why when the client's `WriterTask` would write to the stream, the server's `ReaderTask` would read nothing and remain blocked. But once I put a timeout on the client object in the server, everything started functioning normally.

So, is there a problem if the applications with unique `ReaderTask` and `WriterTask` are on the same machine? When you use a receive timeout, no problems at all. Without receive timeout, it didn't work normally (at least in my case).

Comment: If the client sends data, the server's `Read()` operation would no longer block - from just your description it appears that the client isn't sending anything because it is waiting for data. But it's hard to say without any code. You shouldn't have to set `ReceiveTimeout` to solve this issue.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis Without the receive timeout, after some reads and writes, all of a sudden servers's reader would loop indefinitely in `while(!readTask.Wait(1000))` while the task being blocked at `message = Deserialize<MyObj>(stream);`. Even if the client's writer has written on the stream - which I verified from the logs. Now, this however, I have no idea why it used to happen. See my question for relevant code.